# data not defined in link function after $http request in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code.

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.main',['LiveAPP.factory'])
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location','dataFactory',mainCtrl])

.directive('ratehome',function(){
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
      console.log("NEW",scope.recentArtist)
    }
  }
})


function mainCtrl($scope,$http,$location,dataFactory){

  $scope.getRecentArtists = function(){
     return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/artistsearch',
        params: {getArtist: "all"}
    }).then(function(recent){
      $scope.recentArtist = recent.data

    })
  };

  $scope.getRecentArtists();

  $scope.recentArtist = ""

  $scope.$watch('recentArtist',function(newValue,oldValue){
    $scope.recentArtist = newValue

  })

}
```

**test.html**

```
<ratehome></ratehome>
<ratehome></ratehome>
<ratehome></ratehome>
```

What happens here is upon instantiation of my controller(routing is set up correctly) there is a `$http` GET request that responds with data that I need that gets assigned to `$scope.recentArtist`. I want this data to be accessible in my link function, but it's not. I have a feeling that my directive is compiling before this request is sent. Is there any way around this? What is odd to me is that when I `console.log(scope)` and check in Chrome Developer Tools my data is there. Yet when I `console.log(scope.recentArtist)` its empty similar to its state in the controller. I was thinking I could maybe make the `$http.get` in my directive, but that seems a little awkward to me.

I have been having trouble with this problem for a few days, hopefully somebody can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `angular ui-router` you could also use `resolve`. With `resolve` you can do the `$http` before the controller starts.

> You can use resolve to provide your controller with content or data that is custom to the state. resolve is an optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller.
>
> If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the 
>   $stateChangeSuccess event is fired.
>
> from the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki).

Please have a look at the demo below or this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/vmx6so3v/).

```js
angular.module('demoApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<ratehome></ratehome><ratehome></ratehome><ratehome></ratehome>',
        controller: 'mainCtrl',
        resolve: {
            artists: function (artistsService) {
                console.log('Resolve');
                return artistsService.get(); //'/artistsearch',//artistsService.get();
            }
        }
    });
})
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'artists', MainCtrl])

    .directive('ratehome', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<div id="rateYo"><ul><li ng-repeat="artist in recentArtist">{{artist}}</li></ul></div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log("NEW", scope.recentArtist);
        }
    }
})

    .factory('artistsService', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            console.log('getting');
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://crossorigin.me/http://www.mocky.io/v2/558b30615f3dcbc414067170', //'/artistsearch',
                //params: {getArtist: "all"}
            }).then(function (recent) {
                //console.log(recent);
                return recent.data;
            });
        }
    };
});

function MainCtrl($scope, $http, $location, artists) {

    $scope.recentArtist = artists;
    console.log('ctrl', artists);    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

AS your directive is not using isolated `scope`, that does mean you can directly access your controller scope inside your directive. I'd suggest you to to put that `$watch` inside directive `link` instead of your controller. That would intimate you that the ajax has been completed and data got changed & you get those changed value inside `watcher` function.

**Code**

```
.directive('ratehome',function(){
  return {
    restrict:"E",
    template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
      $scope.$watch('recentArtist',function(newValue,oldValue){
        console.log("NEW",newValue)
      });
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your link function is running before the $http response comes back as you suspect. You can wait for it by [using $broadcast and $on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

```
angular.module('LiveAPP.main',['LiveAPP.factory'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location','$rootScope','dataFactory',mainCtrl])
    .directive('ratehome',function(){
        return {
            restrict:"E",
            template: "<div id='rateYo'></div>",
            link: function(scope, ele, attrs){
                scope.$on('artistLoaded', function(){
                    console.log("NEW",scope.recentArtist);
                });
            }
        };
    });


function mainCtrl($scope,$http,$location,$rootScope,dataFactory){
    $scope.getRecentArtists = function(){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/artistsearch',
            params: {getArtist: "all"}
        }).then(function(recent){
            $scope.recentArtist = recent.data
            $rootScope.$broadcast('artistLoaded');
        });
    };

    $scope.getRecentArtists();
    $scope.recentArtist = "";

    $scope.$watch('recentArtist',function(newValue,oldValue){
        $scope.recentArtist = newValue
    });
}
```

This way the code will not run until the response has been returned and set

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question, but is it good practice to use broadcast to a directive? I was under the impression that $broadcast was mostly a way to communicate across controllers?

Comment: I haven't read either way whether it is good or bad. In my opinion its slightly cleaner than a $watch if you only need to update a few times or once. Since a $watch will run every $digest cycle and the $on will only run specifically when you tell it to run. But like I said I haven't heard either way so I could be subjectively or objectively wrong!